# Unknown arguments at Graphql.js

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

I run a simple graphql code using argument with express-graphql. But graphiql show error message "Unknown argument \"age\" on field \"persons\" of type \"Query\".

This is my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql'); 
var {buildSchema } = require('graphql');

var schema = buildSchema(`
type Query{
    hello: String
    persons: [Person]
}

type Person{
    name: String
    age: Int

}
`);

var root = {
hello: () => 'Hello World',
persons: (args, context, info) => {

    console.log(context);
    console.log(args);
    //Add args
    const {name, age} = args;
    //Add filter
    return [
        {   name: "kim", age:20},
        {   name: "lee", age:30},
        {   name: "yoo", age:40},
    ].filter((person)=>{
        if(!name && !age){return true;}
        if(!age && name && person.name === name){ return true;}
        if(!name && age && person.age === age){ return true;}
        if(name && age && person.name === name && person.age === 
age){return true;}
        return false;
    });
}
};

var app = express();
var session = {id: "1001", expires: 20000};

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
schema: schema,
rootValue: root,
context: session,
graphiql: true,
}));

app.listen (4000, ()=> console.log('Now browse to 
localhost:4000/graphql'));
```

I expected if I query like this.

```
query{
 persons(age: 30){
 name
 age
 }
}
```

then, show data, not error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to fix your query schema! you query requires input and it should be like this:

```
var schema = buildSchema(`
type Query{
    hello: String
    persons(age: Int, name: String): [Person]
}

type Person{
    name: String
    age: Int

}
`);
```